# Is it safe to synchronize a block without using the wait keyword?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I have one thread populating a vector object with values, and one other thread that periodically fetches the values from it and clears it periodically.

I want that either thread accessing the vector pauses while the other one is accessing it. Do I need to use the wait/notify/notifyAll keywords ?

```
private Vector<Long> _recordIdsSent;

# Called by main thread (before thread A and thread B are started)
public ConstructorOfThisClass() {
    _recordIdsSent = new Vector<Long>();
    // Starts thread A & B
}

# Called by thread A
public void addSentRecordIds( List<Long> ids ) {
    synchronized (_recordIdsSent) {
        _recordIdsSent.addAll( ids );
    }
}

# Called by thread B
public void deleteRecords()
{
    List<Long> ids;
    synchronized (_recordIdsSent) {
        ids = (List<Long>) _recordIdsSent.clone();
        _recordIdsSent.clear();
    }

    // Delete the records matching ids....
}
```

Note: I clone the _recordIdsSent vector because the delete operation can take some time.

[EDIT]
Moved the synchronized keyword from the method signature to the variable _recordIdsSent

Comment: You'll need a busy waiting loop somewhere.  Or you could use a thread pool and send directly the delete task to the thread pool (for future processing) from thread A, without using a Vector.

Comment: Ain't this Producer Consumer problem on a high level?

Comment: @Ajay George : As far as I understand the Producer-Consumer Pattern, you need this when you want your data to be consumed as soon as it is available. This is not my case : I am accumulating lots (I mean LOTS) of data per second. I prefer to have a delay in processing the data, then to have my recording thread having to wait for the processing of the data, like it would be if using this pattern.

Comment: @toto : Like I said above, I have lots of data per second, so I can't afford to start unecessary threads.

Comment: @David agree with your point of wanting to accumulate lots of data, but if your processing is slow, wouldn't that affect the overall throughput. In other words, what would be the point if you are continuously loading up data, without being able to process it in time. You could have a pretty large buffer and then once its full, you would wait until the queue depth decreases. Again this discussion is on an architecture level and not really on the code.

Comment: @David That's the point of a thread pool! You don't start any threads.  And by the way, you can have a thread pool with one thread.  The tasks are queued up automatically in a thread pool, so you don't have to have a thread busy waiting. I'm still not quite sure of what you are trying to achieve, but I assume that, despite its name, `deleteRecords` actually does some processing before deleting the records. Right now it seems you are putting stuff in an array and deleting it without doing anything.

Comment: @Ajay George: I had to simplify the problem to get a precise answer. What I am doing actually is recording data from an Android device's sensors and store it in a local SQLite database (Thread 1), and then the bottleneck is when I am sending the recorded data to a server over HTTP (Thread 2). Then I don't need the records on the device anymore and want to delete them, but writing from two threads to an Android SQLite db is very tricky, so Thread 2 is calling addSentRecordIds() and Thread 1 calls deleteRecords() when it's idle.

Comment: As I'm obsessed with thread pool, here's a solution.  Create a thread pool with a single thread, `executor`.  Pass that thread pool to the part of your code that reads the sensor and to the part that sends the data over the network.  After reading the sensor do a `executor.call(storeInDBTask)` and elsewhere, after having sent the data over the network, do a `executor.call(deleteFromDBTask)`.  Both insertions and deletions are handled by the same trade and your code is much simpler.

Comment: @toto : thanks for insisting, you are catching my attention! What should be the type of the executor class?

Comment: @David I made it an answer.  It's OK if you don't make it the chosen answer since what I'm proposing is quite far off your original question. Salut de Montreal... en passant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted, in provided code access to vector from `addSentRecordIds` is not synchronized - that makes your code **unsafe**

Also, this code snippet does not guarantee that object used for locking (`_recordIdsSent`) doesn't change - this makes it **unsafe** too. Myself I typically prefer dedicated objects for locking because it makes my intent cleaner and is less error prone. Like this:

```
private final Object lock = new Object(); // dedicated lock object
//... _recordIdsSent, addSentRecordIds etc...
public void deleteRecords()
{
    List<Long> ids;
    synchronized (lock) {
        ids = (List<Long>) _recordIdsSent.clone();
        _recordIdsSent.clear();
   }

   // Delete the records matching ids....
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more? You mean _recordIdsSent could be changed from another thread?

Comment: well change from another thread may happen but if you don't write the code for that, you're safe in that regard. The really unsafe part of the way you use it as lock is that since `_recordIdsSent` is not final another thread may catch it with pants down. I mean might catch it when it's null, before it's initialized with something else. That's one of the reasons why I proposed `private final Object lock = new Object();` note _final_ here

Comment: The object can't be null how code is written right now, but I understand it is a best practice to have a dedicated final object to it. Thanks!

Comment: well as far as I understand the object _is_ null at the very moment when you coded `private Vector<Long> _recordIdsSent;` - and even if you believe that you re-defined it to something else (from particular thread), the code given does not seem to offer any guarantee that this re-definition will be ever 'noticed' from another thread. Quoting self, "That's one of the reasons why I proposed `private final` etc..."

Comment: I admit it is not obvious is my example above, but in my full code the vector is initialized in the constructor from the "root" thread before threads A & B are started. I edited the example code above to be more accurate.

Answer (score 4):

You dont have to. Just put a synchronized block in `addSentRecordIds` just like `deleteRecords`.
So, you will only access your Vector one thread at a time.

Comment: Your code still wrong... synchronized method locks 'this' instance. So, you have one method synchronized in this and other synchronized in _recordIdsSent. They may execute at same time since each one will check one lock.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the original question, but a suggestion on a different way of tackling the problem at hand.

You could use a single thread pool (java.util.concurrent):

```
Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

and when you want to write/delete to the DB:

```
executor.call(new Runnable() {
   @Override public void run() { ... write to DB}
});

executor.call(new Runnable() {
   @Override public void run() { ... delete in DB}
});
```

Wherever you call those, they'll run in the same thread.

EDIT: from the javadoc of newSingleThreadExecutor:
"Creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread operating off an unbounded queue. (Note however that if this single thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.) Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be active at any given time. Unlike the otherwise equivalent newFixedThreadPool(1) the returned executor is guaranteed not to be reconfigurable to use additional threads."

Comment: Very interesting in that it seems to allow queuing commands for later execution. Does that avoid the thread creation process? e.g. Would it keep the single thread alive forever ? (merci Montréal !)

Comment: I copied the javadoc in an edit above.  I guess that a single thread stays alive all the time.  But if you have more than one thread, things get more complicated and you can configure how long an idle thread stays alive before shutting down and such things (see doc of ThreadPoolExecutor).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to as the synchronized keyword is doing that for you.

Synchronized means that only one thread can be in that block, or any other synchronized block in the class, at a time. This means that if the class has two distinct objects in it that need to be thread safe, and you make the methods that manipulate both of those distinct objects as synchronized, then a thread accessing one of the objects will block other threads from accessing the other object (not ideal), so don't overuse it or you'll counteract all the benefits of having multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the earlier posts, using the synchronized keyword on the methods modifying your data structure will prevent concurrent access and potential corruption of your data.

The value in using wait and notify methods is that the consumer thread (the one reading the data) doesn't have to constantly poll, rather it can be notified by the producer thread(s) when the vector has reached a certain size.